# Load 2 fields only out 4 fields - Pig to Hive table

Tags: hive, hdfs, apache-pig

Pls help advise.

Scenario: Store data from HDFS to Hive using Pig.

I have file that scooped from mySQL, which has 4 fields `Ord_Id, Cust_Id, Cust_name, Ord_date`. I like to Store only 2 fields Ord_Id and Cust_Id to Hive. How could I do it? pls advise.

below code can't execute:

```
pig -useHCatalog
orders = LOAD '<HDFS_file_path>' USAGE PigStorage(',') AS (Ord_Id:Int, Cust_Id:Int, Cust_name:chararray, Ord_date:chararray);
STORE orders INTO 'pig_demo.orders' USAGE org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatStorer();
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your table should already exist in hive with same column names you want to store from pig.

```
orders = LOAD '<HDFS_file_path>' USAGE PigStorage(',') AS 
(Ord_Id:Int, Cust_Id:Int, Cust_name:chararray, Ord_date:chararray);

select_columns = FOREACH orders GENERATE Ord_Id AS ord_id, Cust_Id AS cust_id;

STORE select_columns INTO 'pig_demo.orders' USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatStorer();
```

also refer [HCatalog LoadStore](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HCatalog+LoadStore)

Answer (score 0):

If aim is to just have a table with just two columns in hive , then you can just use SQOOP's `--columns` argument in to specific those two coulmns with `--hive-import` option and avoid using additional PIG script execution altogether.

something like -

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://cloudera.quickstart:3306/retail_db \
--table orders \
--columns Ord_Id, Cust_Id \
--hive-import \
--direct
```